# How can I use the Ubuntu Touch onscreen keyboard on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, touchscreen, onscreen-keyboard

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on an old x86-based tablet and I am trying to get the Ubuntu Touch onscreen keyboard to work, because I'm not satisfied with Onboard. 
I installed the packages "ubuntu-keyboard" and "ubuntu-keyboard-ger" but I can't figure out what to do with them. As far as I know the keyboard is based on the maliit-framework, but sadly the maliit-homeppage is kinda outdated and didn't help me very much.
It seems like I have to start the maliit-server, but whenever I try it I get the message

```
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

(my system language is german)

I think the english expression for that is "segmentation fault" or at least I hope so.